# PyGRASS r.mapcalc crashes with ERROR: Unable to make mapset element

Tags: python, grass-gis, pygrass

I'm trying to load a `GeoTIFF` and then do some calculations on it with `r.mapcalc`

the code is as follows:

```
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import general as g
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r
from grass.pygrass.modules import Module

geotiff = 'C:\\Users\\ac\\Downloads\\gtfis\\11.tif'
output = 'C:\\Users\\ac\\Documents\\GIS_DataBase\\test.tif'
curr_raster='layer_1'
r.external(input=geotiff, output=curr_raster, overwrite=True)
g.region(raster=curr_raster)
r.mapcalc('layer_1 = if(layer_1 > 0, layer_1, null())', overwrite = True)

r.out_gdal(input = curr_raster, output = output, format = 'GTiff', overwrite = True)
```

now to me this looks valid but it chrases at the mapcalc step with the following error:
`ERROR: Unable to make mapset element C:\Users\ac\Documents\GIS_DataBase\test.tif (C:\Users\ac\Documents\grassdata\newLocation\ac/C:\Users\ac\Documents\GIS_DataBase\test.tif): Invalid argument`

and I don't understand why I'm using win10 and grass 7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to overwrite the input with the output in this line:

```
r.mapcalc('layer_1 = if(layer_1 > 0, layer_1, null())', overwrite = True)
```

(note: `layer_1 = if(layer_1 ...`)

Please use a different output name.